# Visual Studio Project User Options Modification

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have made a number of R&D to modify the Visual Studio Projects user options(.suo) programmitcally, but couldn't find a hopeful result. I also find some topic over stackOverFlow like- 
[Tool to view the contents of the Solution User Options file (.suo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052/tool-to-view-the-contents-of-the-solution-user-options-file-suo/54066#54066)
and 
[VS2010 - Open a solution, file in this sln will open too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030864/vs2010-open-a-solution-file-in-this-sln-will-open-too/9031375#9031375)

but all says to use  IVsPersistSolutionOpts interface. I also made some experiments on this interface but still not able to find enough resource to understand this interface.
Actually my purpose is to change my all projects configuration to change programmitaclly. eg- debug or release or other configuration I have created for my projects.

Any Help would be appreciable.
Thanks.